# CSS How do I override a parent style in an external style sheet?

Tags: css

**UPDATE: I have tried the suggestions below, but I'm still facing the same problem. I've edited the code below to reflect the new stylesheet. If it helps, the page in question is http://japanesenostalgiccar.com/2011/05/06/friday-video-nissan-cedrics-vs-s30-fairlady-z/**

In my wordpress blog I'm trying to create a stylesheet where an image or embedded youtube video is 640px wide, while the text beneath it is only 600px wide.

The wordpress-generated HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
    <p>
        <a href="uploads/2011/05/ball.jpg">
            <img class="alignnone size-large wp-image-15139" width="640" height="211"
                src="uploads/2011/05/ball.jpg" title="Ball" />
        </a>
        This is a baseball.
    </p>
</div>
```

My external CSS file has the following:

```
.entry-content p{
    overflow: visible !important;
    padding : 0px 20px 0px 20px;
}

.entry-content p .alignnone, iframe{
    overflow: visible !important;
    width   : 640px !important;
    padding : 0px !important;
}

img.alignnone.size-large{
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: 640px !important;
    padding : 0px !important;
}
```

However, the image (and the text) always displays at 600px, while the embedded youtube videos (using the iframe tag) display at 640px.

Thinking it was a specificity issue, I even added

```
style="width: 640px;"
```

as an IMG attribute, but no dice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm, try adding `overflow: visible` to your paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your updates, I looked at the page in question. I think I might have an answer for you.

Check out the styles that your theme "TwentyTen" is inserting starting at line 778:

```
/*
Resize images to fit the main content area.
- Applies only to images uploaded via WordPress by targeting size-* classes.
- Other images will be left alone. Use "size-auto" class to apply to other images.
*/
img.size-auto,
img.size-full,
img.size-large,
img.size-medium,
.attachment img {
    max-width: 100%; /* When images are too wide for containing element, force them to fit. */
    height: auto; /* Override height to match resized width for correct aspect ratio. */
}
```

The 'max-width: 100%;' line seems to be the issue. Using Firebug, I just turned that style off for a second and the picture of the Nissan snapped out to be full-width. So to solve it, you should be able to add this to your own stylesheet:

```
max-width: none;
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you so much!! This did the trick. I've been racking my brains out forever on this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You have another class on the image of "size-large" - did you check to see what that style is doing to the image? Does that style possibly have a "!important" declaration in it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added that into the .css file but it didn't change the behavior. Please see updates above. It's not a problem with "size-large" because when I remove the padding in "entry-content p" everything displays at 640px.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the other classes on your `img` are doing, but maybe you could try something like this:

`img.alignnone.size-large {width: 640px !important;}`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added that into the .css file but it didn't change the behavior. Please see updates above.  It's not a problem with the other classes because when I remove the padding in "entry-content p" everything displays at 640px.

Answer (score 0):

simple:

```
.entry-content p .alignnone, iframe{
    width   : 640px;
}
```

this will take the child element of p, and set it at 640px;

However, you might need to set the

```
.entry-content p{
overflow-x:visible
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've added that into the .css file but it didn't change the behavior. Please see updates above.

Comment: because there's padding to the paragraph, you'll be able to make it less than 640px if you'll set the width to less than 600px, so to achieve 600px width, you'll need 559px width.

Answer (score 0):

The image is only 600px wide because of the padding on the paragraph tag.

If you want to display the image and the iframe at 640px, you can add the following:

to the image:

```
img {
  margin: 0 -20px;
  display: block;
}
```

to the iframe:

```
iframe {
  margin: 0 -20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try separating the div's i.e.  tags for the text beneath &  that contains the image/video ?
Keep the container that holds (iframe & text) consistent.
Separating the divs for inner elements of the container is a better option.